# Using Namespaces vs Using Classes

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

in c++ what is the difference between using a namespace and a class??

like::
in this example i added namespace

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace ns{

void print(){

cout<<"Hello, World!";

}

}

int main(){

ns::print();

return 0;
}
```

vs:
and in this one i added a class

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


class cs{

void print(){

cout<<"Hello World!";


}    

}


int main(){

cs classOject;
classObject.print();

return 0;
}
```

but both got me the same result;;;
that question made me keep thinking for a week

thanks for any replies guys and all repliers are much appreciated...

Comment: Was half expecting at least a `static` to make this minimally interesting...

Comment: so to get this @manlio all you are trying to tell me, a namespace can be used by making using namespace and call the function directly but the class must have an object and call the objectName.functionName();      is this all the difference??

Answer (score 1):

they are too different to describe here in detail. i recommend you to read something about [oop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Fundamental_features_and_concepts).
classes are definition of objects, and namespaces can be used to build logical groups of code.

Comment: eh? i cant understand anything from wikipedia if u can explain it to me in a simpler way!?

Comment: The simpliest way is to learn and understand the concepts of object oriented programming, then you will understand what classes are for, and then you will see the difference.